# Adding a series of bootstrap buttons inside an HTML canvas and inside a javascript animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code and html page within which is contained a javascript animation (which makes up the whole background in a canvas). I am trying to put the buttons (which are currently displayed on the top left of the page) underneath the main heading. I've tried placing them there, as well as in other places, but nothing quite works. I basically want them in a row DIRECTLY under the heading that says: "Example Heading.Com"

**Code/Html page below**

(The code is quite long, but I thought it necessary to paste it all, with the JS and CSS so as for people to see the whole context)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,400,800" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/css/demo.css" />

<script src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/js/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/js/rAF.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/js/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
/* Header */
.large-header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 1;
}
#large-header {
  background-image: url("https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/img/demo-1-bg.jpg");
}
.main-title {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #f9f1e9;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
.demo-1 .main-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4.2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.main-title .thin {
  font-weight: 200;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .demo-1 .main-title {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}

body {margin:0;}

.icon-bar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow: auto;
}

.icon-bar a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}





</style>
<!-- Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons -->

</head>


<body>

<body bgcolor="#000000">


<!-- Secondary, outline button -->

<div style="padding-left:0px">

</div>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Home</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Button1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Button2</button>

</div>
<div id="large-header" class="large-header">
  <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
    <h1 class="main-title"><span class="thin">ExampleHeading<span class="thin">.com</span></h1>






</div>




<script>
(function() {

    var width, height, largeHeader, canvas, ctx, points, target, animateHeader = true;

    // Main
    initHeader();
    initAnimation();
    addListeners();

    function initHeader() {
        width = 700;
        height = 750;
        target = {x: width/2, y: height/2};

        largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

        canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // create points
        points = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < width; x = x + width/20) {
            for(var y = 0; y < height; y = y + height/20) {
                var px = x + Math.random()*width/20;
                var py = y + Math.random()*height/20;
                var p = {x: px, originX: px, y: py, originY: py };
                points.push(p);
            }
        }

        // for each point find the 5 closest points
        for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var closest = [];
            var p1 = points[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
                var p2 = points[j]
                if(!(p1 == p2)) {
                    var placed = false;
                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(closest[k] == undefined) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(getDistance(p1, p2) < getDistance(p1, closest[k])) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            p1.closest = closest;
        }

        // assign a circle to each point
        for(var i in points) {
            var c = new Circle(points[i], 2+Math.random()*2, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)');
            points[i].circle = c;
        }
    }

    // Event handling
    function addListeners() {
        if(!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck);
        window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    }

    function mouseMove(e) {
        var posx = posy = 0;
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        }
        else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
            posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        target.x = posx;
        target.y = posy;
    }

    function scrollCheck() {
        if(document.body.scrollTop > height) animateHeader = false;
        else animateHeader = true;
    }

    function resize() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }

    // animation
    function initAnimation() {
        animate();
        for(var i in points) {
            shiftPoint(points[i]);
        }
    }

    function animate() {
        if(animateHeader) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            for(var i in points) {
                // detect points in range
                if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 4000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.3;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.6;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 20000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.1;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.3;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 40000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.02;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.1;
                } else {
                    points[i].active = 0;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0;
                }

                drawLines(points[i]);
                points[i].circle.draw();
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function shiftPoint(p) {
        TweenLite.to(p, 1+1*Math.random(), {x:p.originX-50+Math.random()*100,
            y: p.originY-50+Math.random()*100, ease:Circ.easeInOut,
            onComplete: function() {
                shiftPoint(p);
            }});
    }

    // Canvas manipulation
    function drawLines(p) {
        if(!p.active) return;
        for(var i in p.closest) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            ctx.lineTo(p.closest[i].x, p.closest[i].y);
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ p.active+')';
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    function Circle(pos,rad,color) {
        var _this = this;

        // constructor
        (function() {
            _this.pos = pos || null;
            _this.radius = rad || null;
            _this.color = color || null;
        })();

        this.draw = function() {
            if(!_this.active) return;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(_this.pos.x, _this.pos.y, _this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ _this.active+')';
            ctx.fill();
        };
    }

    // Util
    function getDistance(p1, p2) {
        return Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2);
    }

})();
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**What I have tried:**

I've tried putting it inside the divs directly under where the title is, like below, but this places it at the bottom of the page, leaving a lot of space between the title and the buttons. That is the main problem.

```
<body>

<body bgcolor="#000000">


<!-- Secondary, outline button -->

<div style="padding-left:0px">

</div>

<div id="large-header" class="large-header">
  <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
    <h1 class="main-title"><span class="thin">ExampleHeading<span class="thin">.com</span></h1>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Home</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Button1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Button2</button>

</div>





</div>




<script>
(function() {

    var width, height, largeHeader, canvas, ctx, points, target, animateHeader = true;

    // Main
    initHeader();
    initAnimation();
    addListeners();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the div contaning the buttons inside the H1:

```
    <div id="large-header" class="large-header">
       <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
         <h1 class="main-title"><span class="thin">ExampleHeading<span class="thin">.com</span><br>
             <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example" >
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Home</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Button1</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Button2</button>
             </div>
        </h1>     
    </div>
```